# Codeignater Routing not working after delopy to server

Tags: deployment, codeigniter-3, url-routing

Someone help me.

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

config file

```
$config['base_url_front']  = 'http://example.com; 
$config['base_url']        = 'http://example.com'; 
$config['post_image_url']  = $config['base_url'].'assets/images/post_image/';
$config['post_video_url']  = $config['base_url'].'assets/images/post_video/';
$config['art_image_url']   = $config['base_url'].'assets/images/art_image/';
$config['media_video_url'] = $config['base_url'].'assets/images/media_video/';

$config['parent_folder_name'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/';
```

directory structure
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

site available file config:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sourcedirectory
        
        <Directory /var/www/html/sourcedirectory/>
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

I would appreicate any advice... Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTGkX.png

Comment: Did you checked your server software is Apache not an another e.g: Nginx?

Comment: Yes, It is apache 2...